# Updating a SharePoint 2010 list with an email confirmation link

Tags: 2010, list, email

I have a list of 1000+ user accounts for an application, and I need to have each user confirm that they still require access.  I would like to send a form email to all of the users in the list asking them to click on on the link if they still require access, and have that link just simply update a "Required" column in the list.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Eric G

Answer (score 0):

In your column, create a simple number field called trigger with a default value of 0. Create a workflow that fires if the trigger field equals 1 with your link to the to update the field. Go into datasheet view of your list and update the trigger field to 1 and drag it down.

This will fire the workflow off for everyone.